# For-each loop in await all runs simultaneously. What loop to use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

first time making a discord bot (discord.js) and stuck in a situation in which my awaitMessage function all runs simultaneously. For example, when I call the command, it does this in a for each loop of 5.

What is this item? You have 60 seconds!

What is this item? You have 60 seconds!

What is this item? You have 60 seconds!

What is this item? You have 60 seconds!

What is this item? You have 60 seconds!

I looked on stackoverflow and I saw a thread that using a for-of loop in await functions can potentially fix this situation, but I don't know how it can apply to my code. Thanks

```
  var i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * etcList.length));
        message.channel.send("What is this item? You have 60 seconds!", {files: ["./pictures/images/img"+(random+1)+".jpg"]});

        const filter = m => m.content == (etcList[random].toString()) || (m.content==("skip"));
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max:1, time:60000})
        .then(collected => {
            if(collected.first().content == ("skip")){
                return message.channel.send("This question has been skipped! The answer was: " + etcList[random].toString());
            }
            if(collected.first().content == (etcList[random].toString())){
                message.channel.send(collected.first().author + " has won! The answer was: " + etcList[random].toString());
            }

        })
        .catch(err => {
            message.channel.send("Time is up! The answer was: " + etcList[random].toString());
        })
    }
```

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Comment: @AZ_ I did let i =0, still doesn't change the answer, still running at the same time

Comment: I got the issue wrongly, you need to return the promise here i.e. :


return message.channel.awaitMessages

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `message.channel.awaitMessages(...).then(...).catch(...)` use this in for-loop

```
  try {
    let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
      max: 1,
      time: 60000
    });

    if (collected.first().content == ("skip")) {
        return message.channel.send("This question has been skipped! The answer was: " + etcList[random].toString());
    }

    if (collected.first().content == (etcList[random].toString())) {
        message.channel.send(collected.first().author + " has won! The answer was: " + etcList[random].toString());
    }
  } catch (e) {    
    message.channel.send("Time is up! The answer was: " + etcList[random].toString());
  }
```

We use `await` key word here which will 'wait' for function result. You for-loop shoud be placed in function which use `async` keyword on its definition

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that you have to declare the function as `async` e.g. `async questionsInLoop() { ...}`

Comment: What is the problem with the code of TO? What have you changed, and why? Adding just a fixed version without any explanation is, imho, not that useful...

Comment: my function is already running in async run(), is there a reason why the code above will work in a for each loop?

Comment: @RickieCheng the reason is that in your code, you run all awaitMessages in asynchronous way without waiting. In my code i use `await` keyword which 'wait' for the function result

Comment: So I tried implementing it right now, and its printing out the catch statement at the same time, then the prompt 5 times again.

Answer (score 0):

Without refactoring the code you can just add `await` before your promises and wrap it using an `async` function.

Here is an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
async function func() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        await new Promise((res, rej) => {
            setTimeout(() => { console.log('x=>'); res() }, 1000)
        })
        .then(() => console.log('y'));
    }
}
```

Hope this clarifies(or confuses) some things!